# CentOS - Yum not installing postfix - No obvious errors

Tags: linux, centos, yum, postfix, centos-7

When trying to install PostFIX on CentOS 7 using yum:

```
yum install postfix
```

It provides the following feedback and is not installed:

```
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, universal-hooks
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * EA4: 169.255.59.74
 * cpanel-addons-production-feed: 169.255.59.74
 * base: repos-jnb.psychz.net
 * epel: mirror.wbs.co.za
 * extras: repos-jnb.psychz.net
 * nux-dextop: mirror.li.nux.ro
 * updates: repos-jnb.psychz.net
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package postfix.x86_64 2:2.10.1-6.el7 will be installed
Removing postfix.x86_64 2:2.10.1-6.el7 - u due to obsoletes from installed exim-4.89-2.cp1162.x86_64
--> Restarting Dependency Resolution with new changes.
--> Running transaction check
---> Package postfix.x86_64 2:2.10.1-6.el7 will be installed
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
```

I even tried installing outside SSH via Cpanel WHM and this is feedback it gives:

```
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, universal-hooks
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * EA4: 169.255.59.74
 * cpanel-addons-production-feed: 169.255.59.74
 * base: repos-jnb.psychz.net
 * extras: repos-jnb.psychz.net
 * nux-dextop: mirror.li.nux.ro
 * updates: repos-jnb.psychz.net
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
Removing postfix.x86_64 2:2.10.1-6.el7 - u due to obsoletes from installed exim-4.89-2.cp1162.x86_64
--> Restarting Dependency Resolution with new changes.
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Install complete.
```

I am still very new to Linux and CentOS and cannot seem to figure out what is the problem. Actions i have taken:

Rebuilt RPM DB

```
yum remove postfix
yum reinstall postfix
```

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Btw. did you run `yum update`?

Try adding `/etc/yum.conf` with:

```
obsoletes=0
```

Or install `exim` package first:

```
yum --setopt=obsoletes=0 install postfix
```

Comment: Yes I had ran yum update as well 

None of the above resolved the issue, exim was already installed.

Feedback messages are still the same.

Thank you for your feedback nonetheless.